# concatenating two outputs of conv net

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

I am building image classifier with localisation using CNN.

My CNN has image as input, however after last CONV layer i want to split it into two , one part for image classification, and next part for image localisation. 
Needless to say one part should use mean squared error, another one should use binary binary_crossentropy. My structure is something like:

```
input_image = Input(shape=(IMG_W, IMG_H, 3))

# Layer 1
x = Conv2D(32, (3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='same', name='conv_1', use_bias=False)(input_image)
x = BatchNormalization(name='norm_1')(x)
x = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)(x)


# Layer 2
x = Conv2D(64, (3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='same', name='conv_2', use_bias=False)(x)
x = BatchNormalization(name='norm_2')(x)
x = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)(x)
```

now i want to divied it into two Dense (FC) layer

```
   class_layer = x
   class_layer = Dense(256,activation="relu")(class_layer)
   class_layer = Dense(2,activation="softmax")(class_layer)
   model_one = Model(input_image,class_layer)
  model_one.compile(loss="binary_crossentrophy", optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),metrics=['accuracy'])
```

and layer for image localisation

```
     x = Dense(1024,activation="relu")(x)
     x = Dense(256,activation="relu")(x)
     x = Dense(4,activation="relu")(x)
     model = Model(input_image,x)
model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),metrics=['accuracy'])
```

However how can i concat the layes so the result vector will be ( 2 + 4 ) ?
Can i even achieve splitting like this?

I know about `model.concatenate` However this should be called before compiling, so each part wouldnt have different loss function

Thanks for help and answers

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize your model with multiple outputs, and specify losses for each of them. If you want your loss from model_one to have weight `a`, and the loss from model to have weight `b`, so your total loss would look like `a*mse + b*binary_ce`, then you would have something like

```
model = Model(input_image, [x, class_layer])
model.compile(loss=['mean_squared_error', 'binary_crossentropy'],
              loss_weights=[a, b],
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam())
```

See the `loss` and `loss_weights` parameters in the documentation for Model.compile for more details https://keras.io/models/model/.